# Can MarkLogic search flat text files? (i.e. txt, tsv, csv)

Tags: marklogic, nosql

I understand that `MarkLogic` is designed for data wrapped in XML.

I loaded a txt file where the data is delimited by tabs and I have been trying to do a word search on the database where I loaded the `txt` file in any way possible.

I tried using the `search:search` `XQuery` function using the `Query Console` but the result only gives me the first occurrence of the search keyword. I think `MarkLogic` is thinking the whole `txt` file is wrapped in 1 `XML` tag.

I would like to be able to search this flat text file and get search results that would look similar to a Google search results page. Is this possible? How? Or does `MarkLogic` expect all data to be in `XML` format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MarkLogic can manage content in XML, JSON, Binary, or Text.

How did you load the data?  For a tab delimited .csv type file, i'd suggest loading with Content Pump http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/ingestion/content-pump#id_70366

A .csv file is usually an export for a relational table or excel.  In which case, rows become individual documents in MarkLogic.  From your description, it sounds like the document was loaded in its entirety, and not broken down into individual documents. This is easy enough to verify in query console as if you click the 'explore' button, you should see multiple URIs. If you see only one for the document you loaded, then you know the doc was loaded in its entirety as a single document, and that's why you only get one result for the search.

Yes, you can get Google style search results with MarkLogic. You may want to take a look at AppBuilder, as it will generate a search app for you quickly with Google style results and it provides a Google style grammar for searching.  If you want to roll your own, check out snippeting in the REST API.

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-builder/intro#chapter

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/search#id_83997

Comment: Thanks @wpaven. You were right the doc was loaded in its entirety. I am trying to use mlcp on your suggestion and I am running into this:

line 2 is inconsistent with column definition

Comment: What does it mean by column definition? My txt file's first line has the column names and the rest are data. Do I need to create a schema for a txt file? If so how?

Also, when loading the file,

WARN mapreduce.ContentWriter: XDMP-DOCXMLCHAR: Invalid XML character codepoint 19 at ...

I think MarkLogic is not understanding some characters in the file. How do I clean/fix this? The file is an outlook inbox export.

Comment: For a csv file, Content Pump assumes the first row is the names of the columns for the values to be found in following rows.  The assumption is that all rows have the same number of columns/fields. The first error you describe usually occurs when the number of fields for a row isn't equal to the number of fields in the first row of the file. (The first row column names become the XML element names for the fields for the following rows. If there are more values in a following row, what is the column/field name?)

Comment: For the encoding issue, you may want to take a look at -content_encoding for Content Pump in the documentation. If no encoding is specified, MarkLogic defaults to UTF-8. http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/ingestion/encoding#id_86388 But you're seeing a warning, not an error.  Does the doc load?  You may just be dealing with dirty data that requires cleanup either pre/post import to MarkLogic.